# Get value checkbox with the same class

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I need to get values from checkboxes with the same class and different values, to get these values when activate submit bottom and select the different checkbox

```
<script>
  jQuery(.simple_search).click(function(){
    if (jQuery('.skey_send').is(":checked")){
     var s_key=jQuery(".skey_send").val();
     alert("Value is : "+s_key);
    } 
  });
</script>


<input type="submit" class="simple_search" name="send_s" value="GO" />

<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="all" />All
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="card" />Card
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="phone" />Phone
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="price" />Price
```

The Problem´s always I get value from the first checkbox but no when clicking over another or different checkbox

I need to know what I need implement or add in my code for getting value from different checkboxes with the same class when checking

Comment: Assign different `[name]` attribute values and those are radios not checkboxes change `type='radio'` to `type='checkbox`

Answer (score 0):

You are using only class to get value so why it's always get first value.
You missed `:checked` on class when get value.

```js
jQuery('.simple_search').click(function() {
  if (jQuery('.skey_send').is(":checked")) {
    var s_key = jQuery(".skey_send:checked").val();
    alert("Value is : " + s_key);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="simple_search" name="send_s" value="GO" />

<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="all" />All
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="card" />Card
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="phone" />Phone
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="price" />Price
```

Answer (score 0):

**please try this,working for me :)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr=[];
  $(".simple_search").on('click',function(){
 
   $(".skey_send").each(function(){
   var checked_Data=$(this).is(":checked");
   arr.push(checked_Data);
   });
     alert(arr);
  });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" class="simple_search" name="send_s" value="GO" />

<input type="checkbox" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="all" />All
<input type="checkbox" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="card" />Card
<input type="checkbox" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="phone" />Phone
<input type="checkbox" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="price" />Price

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need for the `.each` if they all have the same name

Comment: yes you are right but sometimes it may help.@MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some single quotes, should use the radio type and look for the checked value.  Since these are radio buttons, only one can be set so no need to get a specific one by index or anything.  You can also make the text description clickable if you use a `<label>` around it - I did not do that but it is a suggested for usability.  I removed the conditional and just alert the `undefined` but that could be put back or a default set.

```js
jQuery('.simple_search').on('click', function() {
  var s_key = jQuery(".skey_send[type='radio']:checked").val();
  alert("Value is : " + s_key);// alerts "undefined" if none are set
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="simple_search" name="send_s" value="GO" />

<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="all" />All
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="card" />Card
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="phone" />Phone
<input type="radio" name="s_key" class="skey_send" value="price" />Price
```